# Word validation C#

Tags: c#

```
public string ValidateWord() // A procedure that validates words
{
    string strRet = "";
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a word 3 - 15 chars all lower case...");
    strRet = Console.ReadLine();
    //no validation at the minute....
    return strRet;
}
```

I am trying to make a procedure which will verify a word, should be 3-15 characters and all lowercase. If it is not 3-15 characters and lowercase I need it to repeat the procedure until a word has been entered with the validation rules.

How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In your current code I see no attempts to do any of the validation checks you mentioned...

Comment: have you tried to google : "C# find length of string" and "C# check string for lower case" ? Sounds like HomeWork, if it is you should state it also.

Comment: Asking what to do isn't considered on-topic here. Come to us with an existing problem with existing code, not a request on what code to write.

Comment: If you're on .NET check out [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation). It has extensive documentation with examples.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. People here usually expect a little effort from yourself. (it surely is not hard to google those 2 topics, probably needs less time than writing this post) Furthermore if you present a first attempt to solve this validation problem, you get much more help that a few unusefull comments and may be one answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature is incorrect because the validation should return a `bool`:

```
public static bool IsValidWord(string word) // A procedure that validates words
{
    return word.All(char.IsLower) && word.Length >= 3 && word.Length <= 15;
}
```

Note that the method uses `LINQ`([`Enumerable.All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bb548541(v=vs.105).aspx)), so you need to add `using System.Linq;`.

Now you can call this method until it returns `true` (omitted hints for user).

```
string word = Console.ReadLine();
while(!IsValidWord(word))
    word = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: While I agree that the OP should name his method more appropriately, it seems presumptuous to think that the return type is wrong, as opposed to the method name. OP may have a different algorithm in mind, e.g. cleaning up a string (e.g. removing curse words) or the like. The method name doesn't reflect that, but the method body does suggest it.

Comment: @Flater: _"I am trying to make a procedure which will verify a word, should be 3-15 characters and all lowercase"_

Comment: And that procedure should likely be put where `//no validation at the minute....` currently is, rather than overwriting the entire method body, which also concerns itself with the _retrieval_ of the string. Again, I agree that the OP's method name is wrong, no argument there. But you're dismissing the actual code based on your interpretation of the method name. It's much more likely that the current code is correct (intention-wise), and merely inaccurately named.

Comment: I really don't think that this answer is appropriate. You are disguising the use of LINQ (which the OP most likely does not know what it is), besides answering a *give me teh codez* question

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: i've mentioned that it's LINQ and what he needs to do to make it working. I'm not sure where OP got stuck, maybe this helps to get him back on track.